# How to get specific value from firebase database?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to get geolocation data which are the Latitude and Longitude from Firebase database to perform distance calculation.

This is the method that i used to calculate distance.

```
    namespace CoronaGo
    {
        public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
        {
            FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            protected async override void OnAppearing()
            {
                base.OnAppearing();
                await firebaseHelper.GetAllGetLocation();
            }
            private async void Location_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var GetLocation = await firebaseHelper.GetAllGetLocation();
                try
                {
                    var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
                    if (location == null)
                    {
                        if (location.IsFromMockProvider)
                        {
                            location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest()
                            {
                                DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.High,
                                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                            });
                        }
                        
                    }
                    if (location == null)
                    {
                        LabelLocation.Text = "No GPS Found";
                        UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("Can't Locate Location");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LabelLocation.Text = $"{location.Latitude} , {location.Longitude}";
                        Location current = new Location(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
                        Location redzone = new Location(?????, ?????);
                        double distance = Location.CalculateDistance(current, redzone, DistanceUnits.Kilometers);
                        Distance.Text = distance.ToString("0.000")+" km";
                        if (distance < 1)
                        {
                            UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("You are less than 1km from RED ZONE");
                            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Alert());
                        }
                        else
                            UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("You are in SAFE ZONE");
                    }       
                }
    }
```

What should i write in the "????? , ?????" in order to get the Latitude & Longitude in Firebase database.

Below is my Firebase.cs

```
namespace CoronaGo
{
    public class FirebaseHelper
    {
        FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/");
        public async Task AddLocation(double la, double lo, string loc)
        {
            await firebase
                .Child("RedZoneLocation")
                .PostAsync(new GetLocation()
                { 
                    Latitude = la, 
                    Longtitude = lo, 
                    Location = loc
                });
        }

        public async Task<List<GetLocation>> GetAllGetLocation()
        {
            return (await firebase.Child("RedZoneLocation").OnceAsync<GetLocation>()).Select(item => new GetLocation
            {
                Latitude = item.Object.Latitude,
                Longtitude = item.Object.Longtitude,
                Location = item.Object.Location
            }).ToList();
        }
    }

}
```

And below is my GetLocation.cs

```
namespace CoronaGo
{
    public class GetLocation
    {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longtitude { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please help me, thank you. I am new in xamarin

Comment: Seems like you're just want to read and write two numbers, lat and lon.  Why do you need to do this another way?

Comment: Hi Doug Stevenson, because i want to get the stored location in firebase database and compare with my current location. If the distance between them is less than 1km it will display alert. Iam not sure how to get the value from firebase database.

Comment: It's just two numbers.  You can do whatever you want with them after they're read.

Comment: Sorry Doug Stevenson, but I really want to calculate with the stored location in my firebase database. I already updated the question, would you mind to read again. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had already solve the problem.
Below are my complete source code.
Thank you so much for helping me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using System.Threading;

namespace CoronaGo
{
    
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        /*protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            var loc = await firebaseHelper.GetAllGetLocation();
        }*/
        private async void Location_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var trigger = 0;
            List<GetLocation> GetLocation = await firebaseHelper.GetAllGetLocation();
            try
            {
                CancellationTokenSource cts;
                var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request, cts.Token);
                var loc = await firebaseHelper.GetAllGetLocation();

                if (location == null)
                {
                    if (location.IsFromMockProvider)
                    {
                        location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest()
                        {
                            DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.Medium,
                            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
                        });
                    }
                }
                if (location == null)
                {
                    LabelLocation.Text = "No GPS Found";
                    UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("Can't Locate Location");
                }
                else
                {
                    LabelLocation.Text = $"{location.Latitude} , {location.Longitude}";
                    Location current = new Location(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
                    foreach (GetLocation item in GetLocation)
                    {
                       Location redzone = new Location(item.Latitude, item.Longtitude);
                       double distance = Location.CalculateDistance(current, redzone, DistanceUnits.Kilometers);
                        if (distance < 1)
                        {
                            Distance.Text = distance.ToString("0.00") + " km";
                            UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("You are less than 1km from RED ZONE");
                            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Alert());
                            trigger = 1;
                        }
                        if (trigger != 1)
                        {
                            UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("You are at SAFE ZONE");
                        }

                    }
                }       
            }
            catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Location not supported on device: {fnsEx.Message}");
            }
            catch (FeatureNotEnabledException fneEx)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Location not enabled on device: {fneEx.Message}");
            }
            catch (PermissionException pEx)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Permission failed: {pEx.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", ex.Message, "Ok");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `lat, log` stored like

```
Users
   user_id
      lat
      lng
      other details
```

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
        .child(user_id)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(snapshot.child("lat").toString());
                    double lon = Double.parseDouble(snapshot.child("lon").toString());
                    Location DBlocation = new Location(lat, lon);
                    double kilometers = Location.CalculateDistance(current, DBlocation, DistanceUnits.Kilometers);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi, Arup. Thank you for answering me, but I cannot understand your method. But I had added my source code in the question, do you mind help me to see it